# Safe to run git gc

Tags: git, garbage-collection

I have encountered my first request to run git gc.  The message I received on my last commit was:

```
warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.
```

and ...

```
You may also run "git gc" manually. See "git help gc" for more information.
```

So my question is do I run `git gc --aggressive`, `--auto` `--prune` or `--quiet`.

Essentially I am concerned that I might lose any commit history or disrupt my master branch in any way?

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, `git gc` is safe to run.  It won't throw away any commits reachable from any named reference.  Depending on how you've set the appropriate expiration variable (e.g., `gc.pruneexpire`, `gc.reflogexpire`, etc.) it will possibly throw away commits that are only reachable from the reflog, or aren't reachable at all.  I let `git gc` decide when to prune on its own (looking at those expire settings) and usually do a `git gc --aggressive`.  It displays some stats while it's working.  If you don't want to see those, then add `--quiet`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for advising me.  I've followed your advice with no issues.  Much appreciate

Comment: does it only affects the local repository ?

Comment: Yes.  It only affects the local repository.  That is, the repository that is or contains the current working directory.